# Execute animations sequentially instead of simulatenously using class selector

Tags: jquery, animation, slideup, sequential

Self admitted newbie here, hope this will be a simple solution.

```
$(.classname).slideUp();
```

When I execute the above code, all of the elements slide up at the same time.  Instead, I would like them to perform the animation one after another.

Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: `$(.classname).each()`

Comment: Make sure to add quotes around your `.classname`.

Comment: Tried Melancias solution, like so...

    $('.classname').each(function(){
      $(this).slideUp(3000);
    });

Still executed the animation on the elements simultaneously instead of sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var animInterval = 100; // 100ms interval between animation starts
$('.className').each(function (i, e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(e).slideUp();
    },i * animInterval);
});
```

Comment: This worked amazingly well :D  The e parameter is a reference to the current element in the iteration?

Comment: Yes. DOM's HTML element, you have to wrap it with $(e) if you want to get jQuery element from it

Comment: Beautiful, thanks again.  Really appreciate it.  I also assume "i" is the index of the array of elements.  Can you recommend any jQuery books?

Comment: Cool :)  I had a feeling you'd say that, lol.  Got alot of reading to do, obviously.

Comment: Sorry for playing "smart-ass" :) I know what you mean about "best book", but never used them, docs are best! :)